# asp.net mvc 3 global variables without cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

I have a asp.net mvc 3 mobile application, and by default most of the smartphones have cookies disabled. I need to use some global variables and on desktop version of the site I used cookies to do that. Is there a cookie-less way to store data in session? I've heard of Session Variables but aren't those using cookies as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookieless sessions should do the trick for you.

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

More info on the concept here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your objects aren't user specific you could use [caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx#S7).  If they are user specific, then you will either need to use cookies or [include the session id in the request URI](http://forums.asp.net/p/1355913/2782069.aspx/1?Re%20cookieless%20support).  Doing this does open your application up to [session hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) which can be a security risk depending on how your application works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a parameter in the URL to define a session ID , like http://www.mysite.com/m/{SessionID}/{controller}/{action}/{id} where "m" defines the mobile version of your site and your unique session ID was stored in the URL. All of your ActionLinks would auto-include them.

You would need to store information about the session in some storage on the server (Database, Filesystem, Application Cache).